# iOS iPad panic crash log interpret

Tags: ios, crash, panic

can anyone help me out in interpreting this panic crash log?
this happens during rotation with many images ... it involves javascript if that is of any help.

```
Incident Identifier: AD3EB83A-2379-4876-BCB3-6C9A4B5DC862
CrashReporter Key:   e580be25a4b36b96f0d033b88c3cfebf6232e309
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Date/Time:       2012-06-27 14:26:41.182 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)

panic(cpu 1 caller 0x801c6fdb): mbuf_watchdog: 4 waiters stuck for 12 secs
13872/13872 mbufs in use:
    13868 mbufs allocated to data
    4 mbufs allocated to packet headers
13748/13748 mbuf 2KB clusters in use
0/122 mbuf 4KB clusters in use
31452 KB allocated to network (approx. 98% in use)

mbuf leak detection table:
    total captured: 31701 (one per 500)
    total allocs outstanding: 42
    new hash recorded: 27032 allocs, 26944 traces
    hash collisions: 18 allocs, 4669 traces
    overwrites: 26449 allocs, 0 traces
    lock conflicts: 0

top 5 outstanding traces:
[1] 29 outstanding alloc(s), 30 hit(s), 1 collision(s)
[2] 5 outstanding alloc(s), 26 hit(s), 0 collision(s)
[3] 3 outstanding alloc(s), 2546 hit(s), 0 collision(s)
[4] 3 outstanding alloc(s), 1844 hit(s), 0 collision(s)
[5] 1 outstanding alloc(s), 4662 hit(s), 4661 collision(s)

    trace [1]   trace [2]   trace [3]   trace [4]   trace [5]  
    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ---------- 
 1: 0x801bff71  0x801bff71  0x801bff71  0x801bff71  0x801bff71  
 2: 0x801b0df3  0x801b0df3  0x801b0e2b  0x801b0df3  0x801b0df3  
 3: 0x801bf8b5  0x801c12db  0x801c12db  0x801bf871  0x801b0f39  
 4: 0x801b0c67  0x801c9517  0x801c9517  0x801b0c67  0x801c08bb  
 5: 0x801c12db  0x801cece3  0x801cece3  0x801c12db  0x802b7855  
 6: 0x801c9517  0x801ceb05  0x801ceb05  0x801c9517  0x801be739  
 7: 0x801cece3  0x801e1bd8  0x801e1bd8  0x801cece3  0x8010e8d5  
 8: 0x801ceb05                          0x801ceb05  0x802b91f5  
 9: 0x801e1bd8                          0x801e1bd8  0x802b937f  
10:                                                 0x802b8591  
11:                                                 0x8002425b  
12:                                                             
13:                                                             
14:                                                             
15:                                                             
16:                                                             

Debugger message: panic
OS version: 9B206
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 11.0.0: S
```

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Have a look at symbolicating your crash reports. Have a look at this SO answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1460892/41116

Answer (score 0):

You should use instruments to check memory allocations and memory leaks. It could also be that the app was too long unresponsive and was killed, the text `4 waiters stuck for 12 secs` could indicate that. The crash report content and format is pretty unique, haven't seen that one yet. So these are just guesses.

Comment: this is an old post, but this answer is wrong... It can't be his app that's unresponsive, because this is a *panic* log, which indicates a *kernel* crash. This is also why the format is unique.